# What Can I do to Automatically Restart my App if it Crashes?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm working on a software / hardware combination that will be loaded into an Android Box. I won't be able to visit the locations that my product is installed in frequently, and would like to make sure that if it crashes, the app restarts or just triggers a software update, but the end user should never be able to see the Android Home screen.

What are some ways that I could implement something like this without relying on an external service?

Thanks!

Comment: Found this literally 10 seconds after asking the question ahaha. Might be helpful for those searching in the future: https://pub.dev/packages/flutterplugincrashrestartkt

But by all means, would love to hear more suggestions / approaches!

Comment: i'm not sure exactly what you want to do , but if it crashes then an error or an exception is there , you can check if the exception is caught , restart activity by creating intent that opens the desire activity , this solution concerns the android part

Comment: @Taki it's not as simple as that, sometimes even with a try catch it will force crash an app

Comment: @JelaniThompson, the flutter plugin crash restartkt is not dart 3 compatible. Infact, it is an abandoned project, since 3 years away from last update.